# How to get date of a page (HTML, PHP... etc.) that uploaded in Server?

Tags: javascript, web, google-chrome-extension, web-crawler

I am developing an Application that gets the " Date of Upload " of a Webpage. So, my doubt is How?

Example: I want to get the date of this post. Like when I send this URL to my program it should give date (The day it was uploaded) as output.

I want Date for this URL: http://refer2earn.16mb.com/

Comment: If the server of that page doesn't add a real modification date in the page headers your only hope is that the date is somewhere inside the page as text so you can download the page with XMLHttpRequest or $.ajax and parse it.

Answer (score 0):

from php official documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php

```
<?php
// outputs e.g.  somefile.txt was last modified: December 29 2002 22:16:23.

$filename = 'somefile.txt';
if (file_exists($filename)) {
    echo "$filename was last modified: " . date ("F d Y H:i:s.", filemtime($filename));
}
?>
```

Comment: Hello @Haseeb 
              My doubt is : I want to develop an Application that will fetch the Date of that webpage uploaded to the server.

Comment: if the file will be always static this will work. otherwise in database create a table for storing upload meta data. or

Answer (score 0):

For a more detailed discussion of dates in web pages, please see my answer to [Citation of a website: How to determine the year?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/73635/22966) on Academia.

Determining the date from the page can be complex if the [Last Modification Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/lastModified) is set to the current date. When the date is set to the current date, that usually, but not always, indicates that the page was generated on the fly (e.g. from a database). About the only thing you can do at that point is try to scrape the page for things that look like dates. That can, however, be complex, and usually requires human intervention to determine which date, if any, is the correct one to use.

Below is a bookmarklet that will both show the last modified date and scrape the page for some common date formats:

```js
javascript: void((function () {
    var toRm = document.getElementById('showTagsWithDate');
    if (toRm) {
        document.body.removeChild(toRm);
    }
    var tags = [];

    function addMoreDates(reg) {
        var addTags = document.documentElement.innerHTML.match(reg);
        if (addTags) {
            addTags.forEach(function (newTag) {
                if (tags.indexOf(newTag) === -1) {
                    tags.push(newTag);
                }
            });
        }
    }
    addMoreDates(/(20\d\d|1\d\d\d)[\s\/\-.,]\s*([1-9]|0[1-9]|[1][012])[\s\/\-,.]\s*([1-9]|0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\s*(st|nd|rd|th){0,1}(?=\D)/img);
    addMoreDates(/([1-9]|0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])(st|nd|rd|th){0,1}[\/\-\s]\s*(january|february|march|april|may|june|july|august|september|october|november|december|jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|sept|oct|nov|dec)[\s,.\/\-][\s,.\/\-]?\s*(20\d\d|1\d\d\d)/img);
    addMoreDates(/(january|february|march|april|may|june|july|august|september|october|november|december|jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|sept|oct|nov|dec)[\s,.\/\-][\s,.\/\-]?\s*([1-9]|0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])(st|nd|rd|th){0,1}[\s,.\-]+(20\d\d|1\d\d\d)/img);
    addMoreDates(/\b([1-9]|0[1-9]|[1][012])[\s\/\-.,]\s*([1-9]|0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])[\s\/\-,.]\s*(20\d\d|1\d\d\d)\s*\b/img);
    addMoreDates(/\b([1-9]|0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])[\s\/\-.,]\s*([1-9]|0[1-9]|[1][012])[\s\/\-,.]\s*(20\d\d|1\d\d\d)\s*\b/img);
    addMoreDates(/\b(winter|spring|summer|fall|autumn|january|february|march|april|may|june|july|august|september|october|november|december|jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|sept|oct|nov|dec)[\s,.\/\-][\s,.\/\-]?\s*(20\d\d|1\d\d\d)\b/img);
    addMoreDates(/(20\d\d|1\d\d\d)[\s,.\/\-]\s*(winter|spring|summer|fall|autumn|january|february|march|april|may|june|july|august|september|october|november|december|jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|sept|oct|nov|dec)/img);
    addMoreDates(/\b(20\d\d|1\d\d\d)(0[1-9]|[1][012])(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\b/img);
    tags.sort(function (a, b) {
        var aVal = Date.parse(a);
        var bVal = Date.parse(b);
        if (aVal === bVal) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (aVal > bVal) {
            return 1;
        }
        return -1;
    });
    if (tags.length === 0) {
        tags = ['No dates were detected in the page.'];
    }
    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<div id="showTagsWithDate" style="background-color:white;color:black;">The page was last modified on ' + document.lastModified + '<br>Dates in the HTML in multiple numeric and English language formats:<ul/></div>');
    var myul = document.body.firstChild.lastChild;
    tags.forEach(function (tag) {
        myul.appendChild(document.createElement('LI')).appendChild(document.createTextNode(tag));
    });
    document.body.firstChild.appendChild(document.createElement('BR'));
})())
```

With more processing available than is reasonable in a bookmarklet, you can do a more extensive job of finding dates in the page. However, matching even more possible date formats will increase the number of false positive matches. While you can reject a reasonable number based on dates that appear invalid, you will still have quite a few which are not accurate.

Ultimately, you are probabably best off using the last modification date as reported by the server, unless a human indicates that one of the dates scraped from the page is accurate. Even then the last modification date may be most appropriate, depending on what you are using the date for, which you don't state in the question.